# Declaring an aspect on an aspect

Tags: java, aspectj

I happen to have an `@Aspect` that declares a method that is intercepted by a pointcut of another aspect. The aspects are created with compile-time weaving and the container is instantiated using Spring.

I annotated my aspect with `@Configurable` to tell Spring that the component is being created outside the container. I happen to have a static reference to a `Log` object in this aspect too. To summarize, the code looks something like this

```
@Aspect
@Configurable
public class MyAspect {
    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getClass(MyAspect.class);
    // Autowired dependencies

    // Pointcuts and advice

    // Happens to be a pointcut of some other Advice
    @Asynchronous
    private Object someMethod(...) {
    }
}
```

During AspectJ compilation, I do not see the message I expect, which looks something like this:

```
weaveinfo Join point 'method-call(java.lang.Object mypackage.someMethod(...))' in Type 'mypackage.MyAspect' (MyAspect.java:30) advised by around advice from 'anotherpackage.AsynchronousAspect' (from AsynchronousAspect.java))
```

As expected, the third-party advice is never invoked at this point. However, if I add a simple log entry to my advice, something like

```
log.debug("Join point invoked!");
```

Then the compilation happens correctly and all the aspects are wired (including my third party dependencies) and invoked correctly.

What does adding a log entry do to change my assumptions?

Comment: I don't know about this design.  I love aspects, but I'd be worried about excessive complexity if you persist with this direction.  I can see someone else scratching their head a year from now and saying "What were they thinking here?"  Is there no simpler way to do this?

Comment: It's probably not as bad as it sounds, if you see the system as a whole it might make more sense why I'm going down this route :) The two advice's are entirely unrelated. It just so happens that I depend on a library that uses aspectj, and my aspect depends on the functionality of this library.

Comment: To me it would be cleaner if you encapsulated the logic contained in `MyAspect` in a different class. I tend to treat aspects as entry points and nothing more, allowing you to package the actual logic into a more re-usable component. That way you don't need to deal with this question.

Comment: I know this one is old, but still listed as unanswered. Would you please accept and upvote my answer if it seems appropriate? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is pretty straightforward and not dangerous at all if you know what you are doing. Please apologise that I am not a Spring user and that I prefer native AspectJ syntax to @AspectJ. This little sample runs just fine:

```java
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        someMethod();
    }

    private static void someMethod() {
        System.out.println("Doing something ...");
    }
}
```

```java
public aspect FirstAspect {
    void around() : execution(void *..main(..)) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPointStaticPart + ": " + someMethod("before", "main"));
        proceed();
        System.out.println(thisJoinPointStaticPart + ": " + someMethod("after", "main"));
    }

    private Object someMethod(String position, String methodName) {
        return position + " " + methodName;
    }
}
```

```java
public aspect SecondAspect {
    Object around() : execution(* *..someMethod(..)) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPointStaticPart + ": before someMethod");
        Object result = proceed();
        System.out.println(thisJoinPointStaticPart + ": after someMethod");
        return result;
    }
}
```

The result is as expected:

```
execution(Object FirstAspect.someMethod(String, String)): before someMethod
execution(Object FirstAspect.someMethod(String, String)): after someMethod
execution(void Application.main(String[])): before main
Hello world!
execution(void Application.someMethod()): before someMethod
Doing something ...
execution(void Application.someMethod()): after someMethod
execution(Object FirstAspect.someMethod(String, String)): before someMethod
execution(Object FirstAspect.someMethod(String, String)): after someMethod
execution(void Application.main(String[])): after main
```

If furthermore you are concerned with thhe order in which aspects are applied/executed, please use `declare precedence`.

If you experience problems with accessing e.g. private members, you need to use a `privileged aspect`.

**Update:** Changed usage of `thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart` to `thisJoinPointStaticPart`. That was just a copy & paste error. The result is the same on `execution` join points, but anyway the correction shows better the code's intent.